# How to use JavaFX ListView with complex data?

Tags: listview, javafx, observablelist

I have an `ObservableList<Person>`, where a `Person` has `firstName` and `lastName` properties (in the appropriate JavaFX way), and I want to make a `ListView` that will display the names of the people and reflect changes in both the list and the properties of the individual `Person` objects in the list. How is this best done? There are two issues:

1. We need to make the `ListView` observe the two name properties so it can refresh changes. One way to do this is explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23822550/listview-is-not-reflecting-changes?lq=1) (see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13906139/javafx-update-of-listview-if-an-element-of-observablelist-changes)). However, this solution requires passing an "extractor" to the constructor of the `ObservableList`, and my list already exists (as part of a larger data model). One would think there would be a way to wrap the existing `ObservableList` to add an extractor, but I don't see it in the API. (Well, there is [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#observableList-java.util.List-javafx.util.Callback-), but it treats the list being wrapped as simply a `List` and not an `ObservableList`, so updates to the original list aren't reported. There is also [this method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/collections/FXCollections.html#synchronizedObservableList-javafx.collections.ObservableList-) that creates a "synchronized" wrapper of an `ObservableList`, but it doesn't include an extractor parameter.) Perhaps I should just implement a method to do this wrapping myself?
2. We need to render the `Person` items in the `ListView`. I know how to do this using a custom `ListCell` class, but I'm hoping there might be an easier way since I'm only displaying strings. Relying on `Person.toString` is not the right thing to do, since I may have other views of `Person` that require different conversions of `Person` to `String`. Is there any way to pass a `ListView<Person>` a `Callback<Person,String>` (or something equivalent) to convert the items to strings?

So, in the end, I do have a way to do what I want: write my own wrapper in 1 and use a custom cell factory in 2. I just feel like this requires more work on my part than it should for what I'd think is a relatively common situation. Is there an easier way I'm missing?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602457/add-extractor-to-existing-observablelist

Comment: @James_D: thanks! I somehow didn't get to that page in my searching. I've just started with JavaFX today, and it's been a bit frustrating trying to find this kind of information...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is already answered in the comments to [Add extractor to existing ObservableList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34602457/add-extractor-to-existing-observablelist).

Create a new observable list with an extractor, and bidirectionally bind the content to your existing list. Something along the lines of

```
ListView<Person> listView = new ListView<>();
ObservableList<Person> personList = FXCollections.observableList(person -> 
    new Observable[] {person.firstNameProperty(), person.lastNameProperty()});
Bindings.bindContentBidirectional(model.getPersonList(), personList);
listView.setItems(personList);
```